# Crear un tablero de Carcassonne Junior (Python)

Tags: python-3.7

para dar contexto: Tengo un tablero ya creado y lo que me falta es ser capaz de identificar si la posición de las piezas en un tablero.
Hay tres reglas:

- No se puede poner una baldosa sobre otra
- No se puede poner fuera del mapa de tamaño (self.tamano x self.tamano)
- No se puede poner sola (necesita tener una baldosa arriba, al los lados o abajo)
  si fallas a una de estas reglas la función retorna falso, si sirve le da verdadero.
  esto es lo que llevo hasta el momento:

```py
def calza_baldosa(self, fila, col):   
    #colu = True   
    #fil = True  
    print(f"fila: {fila}")  
    print(f"col: {col}")  
    if 0 <= col < (self.tamano)  and 0 <= fila < (self.tamano):
        if self.tablero[fila][col] == False:
            if col == 0 and fila != 0 and fila != (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila][col+1] != False or self.tablero[fila+1][col] != False or self.tablero[fila-1][col] !=
False:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if col == 0 and fila == 0:
                if self.tablero[fila][col+1] != False or self.tablero[fila+1][col] != False:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if col == 0 and fila == (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila][col+1] != False or self.tablero[fila+1][col] != False or self.tablero[fila-1][col]:
            if col == (self.tamano - 1) and fila != 0 and fila != (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila][col-1] != False or self.tablero[fila-1][col] or self.tablero[fila][col+1]:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if col == (self.tamano - 1) and fila == 0:
                if self.tablero[fila][col-1] != False or self.tablero[fila][col+1]:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if col == (self.tamano - 1) and fila == (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila][col-1] != False or self.tablero[fila-1][col]:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
                
            if 0 < col < (self.tamano - 1) and fila != 0 and fila != (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila][col-1] != False or self.tablero[fila][col+1] != False or self.tablero[fila-1][col] !=
    False or self.tablero[fila+1][col]:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if 0 < col < (self.tamano - 1) and fila == 0:
                if self.tablero[fila + 1][col] != False or self.tablero[fila][col+1] != False  or self.tablero[fila][col-1]:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if 0 < col < (self.tamano - 1) and fila == (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila - 1][col] != False or self.tablero[fila][col+1] != False  or self.tablero[fila][col-1]:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if fila == 0:
                if self.tablero[fila+1][col] != False:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if fila == (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila-1][col] != False:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
            if 0 < fila < (self.tamano - 1):
                if self.tablero[fila-1][col] != False or self.tablero[fila+1][col]:
                    return True
                else:
                    print('No puedes poner la baldosa sola')
                    return False
        else:
            print('Ya esta ocupado este lugar!')
            return False
    elif col < 0 or fila < 0:
        print("No puedes poner baldosas fuera del mapa")
        return False
    elif col > self.tamano or fila > self.tamano:
        print("No puedes poner baldosas fuera del mapa")
        return False
```

Lo único que necesito es saber si estoy cometiendo algún error o si tienen algún consejo de como podría mejorar el código para que corra adecuadamente.

Comment: cambia esas largas condiciones, trata de usar verificación de membresía

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu codigo falla? tene en cuenta que aca no se hacen revisiones de codigo, a menos que tengas un problema...ç

Answer (score 1):

Nota: el código publicado es un método de una clase. Sin tener el resto de la clase, opte por implementar mediante funciones.

Elegi representar las celdas vacías con un valor cero, y las ocupadas con el valor 1. Es posible ocupar otros valores con los ajustes correspondientes.

Hay una solución más simple, corta y general:

```
def evaluar_posicion(tablero, fila, columna):
    if 0 <= fila < filas and 0 <= columna < columnas:
        return tablero[fila][columna]
    else:
        return None

vecinos = [(-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]
def calza_baldosa(tablero, fila, columna):
    if evaluar_posicion(tablero, fila, columna) == 0:
        evaluacion = [evaluar_posicion(tablero, fila + desp[0], columna + desp[1]) for desp in vecinos]
        return sum([x for x in evaluacion if x]) > 0
```

La función `evaluar_posición` recibe el tablero (una lista de listas) y un par de coordenadas. Retorna el contenido de esa celda o `None`, si está fuera de límites.

La función `calza_baldosas` se simplifica. Si la posición recibida como parámetro devuelve el valor cero (celda vacía y dentro de límites), sólo nos queda revisar sus potenciales vecinos. Si devuelve 1, ya está ocupada.

Nos ayuda la lista `vecinos`, que contiene los desplazamientos a sumar para obtener las coordenadas de los vecinos en el tablero. En este caso sólo hay cuatro, pero si se desean examinar también las diagonales, es cosa de agregar más elementos

```
[(-1,-1), (-1,1), (1,-1), (1,1)]
```

El resultado de evaluar las posiciones vecinas resulta en una lista que puede contener valores numéricos o `None`, si un vecino cae en una posición fuera de límites. Por ejemplo:

```
evaluacion => [1, 0, 0, None]
```

Para saber si tengo al menos un vecino, voy simplemente a aplicar `sum` sobre `evaluacion`, pero descartando todo lo que sea *falso* para Python: los ceros y los `None`. Eso se hace con

```
sum([x for x in evaluacion if x])
```

Si el resultado es mayor que cero, tenemos al menos un vecino.

**Demo**

Creamos un tablero inicializado a cero e intentamos colocar una pieza

```
filas = 6
columnas = 8
tabla = [[0] * columnas for fila in range(filas)]

print(calza_baldosa(tabla, 0, 0)) => False
```

Luego colocamos una pieza y vemos si podemos agregar otra al lado:

```
tabla[0][0] = 1
print(calza_baldosa(tabla, 0, 1)) => True
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda 
Lo probaré en mi codigo para ver como funciona!